# How to atomically delete user and user's data from Firebase Auth and Realtime Database respectively?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

**Some background**

When a user account is created, I do 3 things using callback chaining in the sequence 1 > 2 > 3.

1. A user is created in Firebase Auth (the standard way using `createUser(withEmail ...)`)
2. I upload the user's profile picture to Firebase Storage and capture the returned `downloadUrl` for use in step 3
3. I store the user's other information (including the `downloadUrl` from step 2) in a node in the realtime database (keyed by `$userid`)

**Now the problem**

I provide a button called 'Delete account' which should enable the user to delete **everything**. That is, clear all their data in the Realtime Database, clear their profile picture in Firebase Storage, and finally delete their account from Auth. *The important thing is that all these operations should succeed or be canceled if even one fails.*

I've gone through ~10 pages of S/O questions & answers, there was 1 [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451812/android-firebase-multiple-steps-but-save-only-if-all-ok) like this one (it asked about the account creation process...I suppose an answer to that question can easily be adapted here.)

**What have i tried?**

Currently, I use callback chaining like so:

```
// start by atomically deleting all the user data from the Realtime Database using the fanout system.
- get all appropriate locations and save in fanout dictionary
- update all these locations to nil // atomic goodness :)
    -callback:
        -on failure: 
            - just return // no worries, nothing has changed yet :/
        -on success:
            // proceed to delete user files on firebase storage
            - delete path $userid on firebase storage
                -callback:
                    -on failure: // this is bad, no idea what to do :(
                    -on success:
                        // proceed to delete account from Auth
                        - delete user account from Auth
                            -callback:
                                -on failure: // this is terrible, also, it could happen often b/c firebase does ask for re-authentication sometimes :(
                                -on success: // thank goodness! I have an authListener somewhere ready to show the 'signInViewController' :)
```

How do you handle such multi-system (Auth, Storage, RealtimeDB) operation atomically? I have looked into *transactions* but can't see how they can be adapted for this - the docs only show them being used in incrementing counters for likes/stars etc in the RealtimeDB.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem is what to do if the data you're trying to delete is being deleted only partially.

I think you should think about a method that will help you restore it if something goes wrong.

I'm not on my computer now but I suggest you to try to download the data that you want to delete and only if there were a success you delete the local copy too, otherwise you should be able to restore it easily.

Edit: if we talk about a serious amount of storage instead of a local copy you can make it on the cloud.

So you first copy this data, then delete it, then delete the database data (also copied previously) then you can delete the user account and finally you can delete the copy.